# ColdFusion page not visible in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to open a coldfusion page into a jquery dialog.  The coldfusion page is data-driven and also includes a form.  When I click on my link, the dialog appears, but it is blank.  If I put simple text into the CFM page, it appears just fine.  Is what I am attempting to do even possible?  Thanks.

Here is my jquery code and the associated div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#somediv a').click(function () 
    {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').load($link.attr('href')).dialog({
        title: $link.attr('title'),
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 300
        });
        return false 
    });
});
```

```
  <div id="somediv">
       <a href="mypage.cfm" title="MyTitle">test</a>
  </div>
```

At the top of mypage.cfm, I have the following:

```
 <!---GENERAL--->
 <cfparam name="activitylocationdateid" default="0">
 <cfparam name="activityid" default="0">
 <cfparam name="activitylocationid" default="0">
 <cfparam name="activitytype" default="">

 <!---TODO--->
 <cfparam name="task" default="">
 test
 <cfabort>
 <cfparam name="deadlinedate" default="#d#">
```

The word "test" displays on my dialog.  When I move the test after the next line, the word "test" does not display in my dialog.

OK...This is most of the page in question...When I uncomment the date params at the top, it does not display in the dialog.  When they are commented out, it displays in the dialog.  What the heck is going on with just these params?

```
<cfparam name="activitylocationdateid" default="0">
<cfparam name="activityid" default="0">
<cfparam name="activitylocationid" default="0">
<cfparam name="activitytype" default="">

<!---
<cfset deadlinedate=thedate>
<cfset apptstartdate=d>
<cfset meetingstartdate=d>
<cfset meetingenddate=d>
--->

<!--- To Do--->
<cfparam name="task" default="">
<cfparam name="deadlinetime" default="12:00 PM">
<cfparam name="priority" default="NRM">
<cfparam name="todoprivate" default="N">


<!---APPOINTMENT--->
<cfparam name="apptstarttime" default="12:00 PM">
<cfparam name="apptdesc" default="">
<cfparam name="selectedorg" default="">
<cfparam name="apptprivate" default="N">
<cfparam name="hide" default="">
<cfparam name="show" default="display:none">
<cfparam name="organization" default="0">
<cfset from="manageappt.cfm">

<!---MEETING--->
<cfparam name="mtgprivate" default="N">
<cfparam name="companyid" default="0">
<cfparam name="meetingtime" default="12:00 PM">
<cfparam name="purpose" default="">
<cfparam name="selectedcompany" default="">



<cfif activitylocationdateid NEQ "0">
    <cfquery name="qdetail" datasource="#request.dsn#">
        SELECT activityid
        FROM activitylocationdate
        WHERE activitylocationdateid=#activitylocationdateid#
    </cfquery>
    <cfscript>
        activityid=qdetail.activityid;
    </cfscript>

</cfif>



<cfif activitytype NEQ "">
    <cfswitch expression="#activitytype#">
        <cfcase value="APT">
            <cflocation url="manageappt.cfm?apptback=close&activityid=#activityid#" addtoken="no">
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="MTG">
            <cflocation url="managemeetings.cfm?mtgback=close&activityid=#activityid#" addtoken="no">
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="TDO">
            <cflocation url="managetodo.cfm?tdoback=close&activityid=#activityid#" addtoken="no">
        </cfcase>
    </cfswitch>
</cfif>



<cfscript>
    nomenu="1";
    if (activitylocationdateid EQ "0")
        PageTitle="Add Calendar Item";
    nobanner="1";
    mainwidth="80";
    nominwidth="1";
</cfscript>

<cfinclude template="_sections/secheader.cfm">
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="_scripts/jquery.ptTimeSelect.css" />
<script src="_scripts/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function type_click()
    {
        var type = $("#activitytype").val();

        var typelist = "APT,TDO,MTG";
        var typearray = typelist.split(",");

        for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
        {
            if (typearray[i] == type)
                $("#" + typearray[i]+"div").show();
            else
                $("#" + typearray[i]+"div").hide();
        }

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[name="meetingtime"]').ptTimeSelect();
        $('input[name="deadlinetime"]').ptTimeSelect();
        $('input[name="appttime"]').ptTimeSelect();

    });
</script>



<cfinclude template="meetingqueries.cfm">

<cfform name="CalendarForm">
    <label>Select Item Type</label><br>
    <cfmodule template="customtags/selectcode.cfm" exclude="EVT" nameid="activitytype" category="Activity Type" selected="#activitytype#" onclick="type_click()">
</cfform>
```

Comment: So to be clear, you put simple text in mypage.cfm and it works, but not what you really want? Can you try slowly adding in the original code until it breaks? That may reveal the culprit. Is it online where we can see?

Comment: I had already put the word "test" at the very top of my full page, and that displayed in the dialog no problem.  I have a few cfparams at the top of my page.  When I put the test text after the cfparams, nothing displays.

Comment: So try ONE cfparam. Does that break it?

Comment: Apparently, when there is a line that includes a "#", it breaks.  I would imagine this is because jQuery uses this, and of course CF uses it.  If I recall, there is a way to change the character that jQuery uses for identifying elements?

Comment: I was thinking of the noconflict command, which prevents conflicts with the $ used by jQuery and other frameworks.  Is there a way to change the # selector to a different selector?

Comment: Wait... I'm confused. jQuery does not care about the character #. All you've asked jQuery to do is to make a HTTP request and include the results inside the dialog. The characters in that request can certainly include a #. Can you *please* put this online so we can see? This smells like something that could be fixed super fast if we could just see it.

Comment: I was just conjecturing since the line where it breaks down is the first line with a #.

Comment: Do you mean to put that `cfabort` below your `test` string?

Comment: Yes.  I had put that there for testing purposes.  When I put the test and cfabort after the line with the #d#, the dialog is blank.

Comment: So- any chance we can see this online? This is the third time I've asked. If you said already you can't, I haven't seen it.

Comment: It is not online.  It is only on my local machine at this time.

Comment: Any chance you could push it up real quick? Also, if you open your DevTools in your browser, and look at the network request, what do you see?

Comment: Issue was solved.  I'm such an idiot.  See below.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<cfparam name="deadlinedate" default="#d#">
```

I guess this is what is breaking it. I do not see any variable "d" declared or paramed anywhere in your code. Either param your "d" before you use it, or use any other hardcoded date in your statement and it should start working.

Comment: d comes from the query string.  The main page is a calendar with each calendar day as a button.  When a button is clicked, it opens up the main page with the date as the parameter.  I changed these from cfparams to cfsets, but there was no change in the result.  It is still not displaying in the dialog.

Comment: I am such a butthead.  I was temporarily using a test link to not affect my existing code, but the test link didn't have the d parameter!  ARGH! !@#$%&!!!!